# Java build path error when importing "javax.swing.SwingWorker"

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I'm new to JAVA and I've been stuck on this one for a while - any help would be much appreciated.
Whenever I import specifically "javax.swing.SwingWorker", it gives me an error called "**The type javax.swing.SwingWorker$SwingWorkerPropertyChangeSupport cannot be
resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files**"
If I don't import it - everything works great.
Might note that the code does work on a friend's computer

So far I have tried "Project> Clean" and adding build path JRE Libraries

Comment: [mcve] - otherwise it's guess work

Comment: And please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].